# Remove Alarm Tone?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, alarm, delete, custom-sounds

Last year I bought an RCA Voyager (tablet) running android 6.0.1 (marshmallow), and between now and then I have added custom tunes to my 'Alarms' folder to spice things up a bit.

My problem is that I accidentally added an alarm that I do not wish to use. I searched the whole clock app for a remove or delete option, but could not find one. I deleted the tone directly from the 'Alarms' folder, but it is still registered in the list (only it now uses the default sound). I attempted clearing the application's data, that didn't work either. I downloaded an app for removing ringtones and alarm tones, but it would not even run. I went as far as installing an app that can access the `/system` directory, but it was too complex in there and I did not want to break anything. My  device is not rooted.

So this really boils down  to: is it at all possible to remove custom alarm tones?

Comment: Did you rebootb after deleting? Wondering if it was removed but it shows the name. Reboot causes `media scanner` to index the files again and you may find it gone

Comment: Yes, i did try rebooting. It didn't work. I wonder if there is a config file of some sort that I can manually change?

Comment: Hi. Are you using the Google's Clock app (default clock app in many Android devices)? In that app if you long-press on the custom tone you would get the option to remove it. Is that option not available or not working? https://i.stack.imgur.com/guf2x.png

Comment: @beeshyams I'm not entirely sure what you mean. There is a directory called `/`, if that's what you meant. There is also [this](https://i.imgur.com/OgLcYWq.png).

Comment: @Firelord I did try the long-press, it didn't work. Yes, I am using the default clock app for android 6.0.1. It looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/18M4n6M.png).

Comment: @CardinalSystem I tried Android-x86 6.0.r3 release which is technically the stock Android for a tablet. I was able to remove the custom alarm tone entry from that list by renaming that sound file (remove .mp3 extension) where it is originally located. That triggered Media Scanner and the entry was dropped from the list. You can rename it back. Alternatively, since the details are stored with external.db of Media Storage, you would have to edit out the entry. Try the first approach though.

Comment: @beeshyams I tried a one minute long-press, it did not work :(

Comment: @Firelord i tried the first method, but the alarm remained registered. Only this time it had the default sound.

Comment: Seeing that no non app solutions have come up suggest try [Ringdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ringdroid). It's open source and well rated

Comment: @beeshyams I tried that app, it only deletes the audio file. The name is still registered in my alarms only it plays the default sound.