# How to remove added ringtone

Tags: ringtone, 8.0-oreo, moto-x4

I have added a new ringtone to the ringtones list in Settings->Sounds->Phone ringtone>Add ringtone. After that I can see the same ringtone file in Ringtones folder of Internal storage. I need to remove this ringtone? For that I have deleted that file from folder. But, the ringtone is still running there. How to remove it.

Device: Moto X4 Oreo 8.0 (non rooted)

Comment: If you don't want to see that file, try removing the extension say MP3 and rename it to something else like PDF . That should prevent it showing up. This was a suggestion by [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188064/remove-alarm-tone#comment242763_188064)

Comment: I have deleted that mp3 file from Ringtones folder. But, still that name(filename) is listed on ringtone list and plays on testing ringtone. Do I need to clear cache of settings app? Similar to above Fielord commented question for alarm sound, and that of mine about ringtone.

Comment: If you rename it , it won't be recognised as tone and after reboot when media scanner is forced, it should vanish theoretically. Not tried

Comment: Now I just cleared cache and data of file manager. Also, removed the same ringtone from Downloads folder. After, refresh ringtone list got reset. Downloaded file.ogg tone(kept in Downloads folder), set ringtone through settings. It created a new folder named Ringtones and saved file.ogg in it. I have deleted this file(file inside Ringtone's folder). But, only after deleting source(Downloads folder), ringtones got reset. Why?

Comment: No idea. That possibly could be a separate question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't clear data of Media Storage (System App) as mattm suggested, you'll lose all ringtones and sound effects.

Instead, do a search for the ringtone or sound effect you added using the Files app (comes with Android), then erase it. It'll be removed from the ringtone selection menu without erasing all the other sound files.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks! The unique drawback is that the Google Files app will show you all files with the same name and you have to open its detailed information to see where it's in the system folder, before decide to remote it. You have to do that, file by file, until you are sure it's the file in the notification ringtones you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you because I also hate the this problem.
You need clear data of **Media Storage**(System App)

1 - Go to "Settings > Apps"

2 - You need enable "Show system apps"

3 - Search and open "Media Storage"

4 - Click in "Storage > Clear data"

5 - Reboot your phone for enable default config.

Answer (score 1):

This is tried on an Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1 running Android 9. Inspired by [Joao's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207467/67410) I didn't use the `Files` app, but connected the phone to a PC using USB cable in file transfer mode, and then used Windows Explorer search to find the file.

Found the folder containing the file: `\Notifications`. If you delete from this folder, your file will be gone from the list of ringtones.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file browser, find music (and its file path) which you like to remove from ringtone selection screen. Beware of duplicate file.

After you find it, please rename the song; add a symbol or character at the beginning or the end of the file name(s).

Now, open ringtone selection screen. The system will not found file(s) and remove them from selection list.

After those files are removed from the selection list; reopen the file browser, rename back to the original name.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check a path in Main Storage called `Ringtones`. It might include added ringtones, so removing them from this path could remove them from options.